# Give credentials to UTL_MAIL.SEND to bypass ORA-29278

Tags: sql, oracle, email

I am trying to send email from a PL/SQL program using UTL_MAIL.Send packaged procedure. But I am getting the following error:

> ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available

I searched on web, and found that this error occurs because there is no SMTP service on the host running my Oracle database.

Now if I want to use another SMTP server, for example , hotmail's "smtp.live.com", i need my user name and password.

How can I give my password into the `UTL_MAIL.Send` procedure call?

(according to my understanding, in order to use any other SMTP server, I have to provide my username/password). I know that to use `UTL_MAIL` package, we set the SMTP server with an initialization parameter, and we can give username in  "Sender" parameter, but the question is where should we give the password?

Comment: [This Link might Interest you!](http://groglogs.blogspot.in/2013/06/plsql-oracle-send-mail-through-smtp.html)

Answer (score 4):

Basically you have to use the "lower level" [`UTL_SMTP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm) package in order to send the various SMTP messages required by the distant SMTP server.

### Authentication

From [Stefano Ghio's blog](http://groglogs.blogspot.in/2013/06/plsql-oracle-send-mail-through-smtp.html):

```
 -- prepare base64 encoded username and password
 l_encoded_username := UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(username)));  
 l_encoded_password := UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(password)));

 -- Open connection and send EHLO and AUTH messages  
 l_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(smtpHost, smtpPort);  
 UTL_SMTP.ehlo(l_conn, smtpHost);--DO NOT USE HELO  
 UTL_SMTP.command(l_conn, 'AUTH', 'LOGIN');  
 UTL_SMTP.command(l_conn, l_encoded_username);  
 UTL_SMTP.command(l_conn, l_encoded_password);
```

The main issue here is that you need be able to send the `AUTH` message using the "right" authentication scheme for your server. I can't say for *"smtp.live.com"* specifically, but depending the server's configuration, they might be different authentication scheme, like `PLAIN` and `LOGIN`, `DIGEST_MD5`, ... Usually (always ?) the parameters (`username`, `password`) are base64 encoded.

### Sending mail

But *the bad news* is, since you are now using a low-level library, you have to implement the client part of the [SMTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) yourself. From the same source as above (edited by myself to only keep the *absolutely minimum necessary stuff*):

```
UTL_SMTP.mail(l_conn, mailFrom);
UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_conn, rcptTo);
[...]

--start multi line message
UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_conn);

--prepare mail header
UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_conn, 'To: ' || rcptTo || crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_conn, 'From: ' || mailFrom || crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_conn, 'Subject: ' || messageSubject || crlf);

--include the message body
UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_conn, messageBody || crlf || crlf);

--send the email and close connection
UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_conn);
UTL_SMTP.quit(l_conn);
```

### Using SSL/TLS

And now, for the **very bad news**: some server required a *secure connection*. Claiming something like `530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first`. Unfortunately, [`UTL_SMTP.STARTTLS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_smtp.htm#BABJBFGH) is only supported starting from Oracle Database 11g release 2 (11.2.0.2).

If you are lucky enougth to use a recent version of Oracle, you should write something like that to open a secure connection with your server:

```
l_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(l_conn, smtpHost,
    wallet_path => 'file:/oracle/wallets/smtp_wallet',
    wallet_password => 'password',
    secure_connection_before_smtp => FALSE);
UTL_SMTP.starttls(l_conn);
```

To quote Oracle's documentation:

> SSL/TLS requires an Oracle wallet which must be specified when the connection was opened by the OPEN_CONNECTION Functions.

Please see the corresponding documentation to see [how to create and manage wallet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asowalet.htm#i1009041)

---

Few more readings:

- [Oracle's documentation about sending e-mail from PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_we.htm#ADFNS1001)  has some nice examples too depicting you to properly send your mail message using `UTL_SMTP`.
- See the [SMTP Authentification Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication#Details) for a transcription of a typical SMTP session.

Answer (score 0):

found this online.  seems like either of these should do the trick:

AUTH PLAIN

```
v_plain_string :=
     UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(
        UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('my_user_name'||chr(0)||'my_user_name'||chr(0)||'my_secret_password'))
    );

v_connection := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(:v_smtp_server);
UTL_SMTP.ehlo(v_connection, 'mydomain.com');    -- Must use EHLO  vs HELO
UTL_SMTP.command(v_connection, 'AUTH', 'PLAIN ' || v_plain_string);
```

AUTH LOGIN

```
v_username_b64 :=
    UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(
        UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(:v_username))
    );
v_password_b64 :=
    UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(
        UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(:v_password))
    );
v_connection := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(:v_smtp_server);
UTL_SMTP.ehlo(v_connection, 'mydomain.com');    -- Must use EHLO  vs HELO
UTL_SMTP.command(v_connection, 'AUTH', 'LOGIN');  -- should receive a 334 response, prompting for username
UTL_SMTP.command(v_connection, v_username_b64);   -- should receive a 334 response, prompting for password
UTL_SMTP.command(v_connection, v_password_b64);   -- should receive a 235 response, you are authenticated
```

also i think when you talk about the "Sender" parameter you might be referring to the "From" header for the email itself.