# SMTP error while I am trying to run the sending email program in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

When I am running this, i am getting error:

```
begin
UTL_MAIL.SEND(SENDER =>'admin@dbaclass.com',
RECIPIENTS=> 'support@dbaclass.com',
SUBJECT=> 'MAIL FROM dbaclasss SENDER',
MESSAGE => 'Welcome to dbaclass'
);
end;

Error:

Error report -
ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 654
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 671
ORA-06512: at line 2
29278. 00000 -  "SMTP transient error: %s"
```

I checked the telnet command to check the stmp.gmail.com its working fine.
but when i tried this from oracle  it is giving the above error.

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Is `smtp_out_server` set correctly? you can check with  `select value, display_value
  from V$PARAMETER
 where NAME = 'smtp_out_server'`...

Comment: Possible solution - Enable Enable access control list (ACL)

Comment: @Plirkee- I searched and found :
value                               display_value
smtp-server.gmail.com smtp-server.gmail.com

is this correct or need to change ?

Comment: @Nitish- can you please tell how to enable, i already created ACL 
but still not working

Answer (score 0):

That will not work out of the box.

If your server is not ssl/tls you need at least set (maybe create local smtp first for test) and set acl:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET smtp_out_server = 'mailserver.domain.com'
```

If server is secure (and gmail is) and you have no local smtp server to work with. You need to do more to set secure connection.
Look at this to get idea for start(you need walled or own secure ssl/tls implementation):

- [Give credentials to UTL_MAIL.SEND to bypass ORA-29278](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186179/give-credentials-to-utl-mail-send-to-bypass-ora-29278)

Probably at this too:

- http://oracle.ninja/sending-secure-e-mails-out-of-the-database-ssltls-utl_smtp-openssl-acl-wallet/